# Redirect Rule not working for index.php in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have site on `http://example.com/~myhome/`. I want to redirect `http://example.com/~myhome/dir1/` to `http://example.com/~myhome/dir2/` on temporary basis.

I wrote the following lines in my `.htaccess` which is inside the `dir1`

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 302 /~myhome/dir1/ http://example.com/~myhome/dir2/
Redirect 302 /~myhome/dir1/(.*) http://example.com/~myhome/dir2/$1
```

Problem with this code is that, this is redirecting every file in `dir1/` to `dir2/` correctly but `index.php` which is redirected to `http://example.com/dir2/index.php`.

Comment: No this is not working. And yes browser has cached the old 301 redirect. I cleared the cache and my code worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need following lines in my .htaccess which is inside the dir1:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~myhome/dir2/$1 [L,R]
```